# How to iterate rows one by one of my database in WinForms DataGridView window

Tags: c#, database, winforms, iterator, iteration

I want my method to be able to display one by one row on DataGridView by clicking button with MoveNext() method. With this code below it works only partially. When I'm clicking on the button I always get only row with id 1 and its not iterating through table. And I understand that is happening because "_position" variable has always value "1" even though I made position++ on the method. I tried to apply Iteratior design pattern but I dont really know how to use it on datatables (Only know how to use it on lists) and it didn't worked for me.

```
 public class AlphabeticalOrderIterator : Iterator
{
    
    SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\****\Documents\Hoteldb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
    
    private int _position = 1;


    public override void MoveNext(DataGridView grid)
    {
        Con.Open();

        
        string Myquery = "select * from Client_tbl where ClientId = '" + _position + "' ";
        _position++;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(Myquery, Con);
        SqlCommandBuilder cbuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
        var ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        grid.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < grid.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            grid.Columns[i].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
        }
        grid.Columns[grid.Columns.Count - 1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;

        for (int i = 0; i < grid.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            int colw = grid.Columns[i].Width;
            grid.Columns[i].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;
            grid.Columns[i].Width = colw;
        }
        Con.Close();
    }
    
}
```

Comment: What is the intent? you want to show only one item in your grid at any given time?

Comment: *Separation of concerns* is not exactly a concern here. You really need to modify (or, actually, create it, since it doesn't exist for now) the `MoveNext()` logic so that it handles its own task an that task only. Opening a database connection (btw, badly), filling a DataTable (btw, badly), configuring a DataGridView (btw, badly) and moving the `Current` item are completely different things that don't belong in the same method.

Comment: @Bharat Yes. I want only one at the time